# Javascript calling a class function

Tags: javascript, class, function, scope

I'm trying to call a class function:

```
// Gantt chart object
function ganttChart(gContainerID) {

    this.isDebugMode = true;                                    // Is this chart in debug mode
    this.gContainer = document.getElementById(gContainerID);    // The container the chart is built inside
    this.gDebugPannel;                                          // Debug pannel

    // Create debug pannel
    if (this.isDebugMode) {
        this.gContainer.innerHTML += "<div id=\"gDebug" + gContainerID + "\" class=\"gDebug\">cometishian</div>";
        this.gDebugPannel = document.getElementById("gDebug" + gContainerID);
    }

    gDebug("lmfao!");

// Updates debug information
function gDebug(debugMessage) {
    alert(this.gDebugPannel.innerHTML);
    if (this.isDebugMode) { this.gDebugPannel.innerHTML = debugMessage; }
}
}
```

I expect it to alert "cometishian" but `this.gDebugPannel.innerHTML` is null, any ideas?

Upon further investigation this.gDebugPannel is undefined.

Update:

```
// Gantt chart object
function ganttChart(gContainerID) {

    this.isDebugMode = true;                                    // Is this chart in debug mode
    this.gContainer = document.getElementById(gContainerID);    // The container the chart is built inside
    this.gDebugPannel;                                          // Debug pannel
    this.gPosX;
    this.gPosY;

    // Create debug pannel
    if (this.isDebugMode) {
        this.gContainer.innerHTML += "<div id=\"gDebug" + gContainerID + "\" class=\"gDebug\">5,5 | 5.1</div>";
        this.gDebugPannel = document.getElementById("gDebug" + gContainerID);
    }

    // Updates debug information
    ganttChart.gDebug = function(debugMessage) {
        if (this.isDebugMode) { this.gDebugPannel.innerHTML = debugMessage; }
    }

    this.gDebug("wo");

}
```

the line this.gDebug("wo") throws:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3)
Timestamp: Thu, 25 Nov 2010 12:57:51 UTC

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 21
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://server1/bb/ganttnew/gMain.js
```

Comment: The statement `this.gDebugPannel;` does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function on the `this` instance, like this:

```
gDebug.call(this, "Hi!");
```

The correct way to do this is to put the function in the class prototype: (This should be done after declaring the constructor function)

```
ganttChart.prototype.gDebug = function(debugMessage) {
    alert(this.gDebugPannel.innerHTML);
    if (this.isDebugMode) { this.gDebugPannel.innerHTML = debugMessage; }
}

this.gDebug("Hi!");
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, why does this work when passing in two parameters though when the function is defined as accepting 1?

Comment: @Tom: The `call` method takes the context (`this`), followed by the parameters to pass to the function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Thanks!  I've prototyped it as you say (I want to do this properly) but I get an error, could you look at the updated code if its not too much of a problem for you

Comment: Ah instead of ganttChart.gDebug it should be this.gDebug right?

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it as

```
this.gDebug= function(debugMessage) {
    alert(this.gDebugPannel.innerHTML);
    if (this.isDebugMode) { this.gDebugPannel.innerHTML = debugMessage; }
}
```